# Determine if process is done?

Tags: vb.net, process

**Background**

I am trying to think of how to logically tell if a process is complete. I currently have a separate program that generates a text file with then name "Information" for its title bar.  When the information text file appears, the program is dumping a whole bunch of data to it. This can take a few seconds or many depending on the data. Basically I am trying to think of the best way for me to tell when that file is done being written to.  Keep in mind that when I say text file, it is not the same as notepad as it does not have a physical file location. It is merely a part of the program that generates it.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> Private Shared Function FindWindow(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As IntPtr
End Function

Dim proc As Integer
    Do Until proc <> 0
        proc = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Information")
    Loop
```

I was thinking that I could possibly use the process ID and determine how much of the CPU it is using.. if it is high then the process is currently in use, and if low then it is done.  The above code has no problem finding the process.

Is this a good approach to tell if it is done?  If so, how do I determine CPU usage based on a process ID?  There may be a better method than I am thinking of.

Comment: I have noticed that the process class has many properties.. Perhaps one of those would lead to my Information window?  I did look and tried going through all of the threads the process has but sometimes there are many and sometimes there are few.. depending how big of a data file it needs.. so not very reliable

Answer (score 0):

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")
process = processes[0]
    process.WaitForExit()
```

But that will freeze program until process it's done.
So incorporating background worker as Ayush said.

```
Private Sub StartButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) _
                              Handles StartButton.Click

    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                                     ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) _
                                    Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")
    process = processes[0]
    process.WaitForExit()
```

"you can put some code here for when it's done or below method.

```
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) _
          Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
```

"this will get called when bw done

```
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not work. My program is NOT starting the process. Also at no point does the window itself close. It simply finishes what it is doing.

Comment: You've mixed C# and VB.NET syntax. The correct (and short version) should be: `Dim process As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")(0)`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the BackgroundWorker control in Visual Basic, it has an event called "Run Worker Completed" which will be raised when the task is successful, failed or cancelled.

Comment: Take a look at this [website](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker-vbnet).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to his question, nor does it show him how to use the BGW. Provide sample code rather than links or nothing at all.

Comment: I thought the website will teach Eric how to use the control more thoroughly than I could, but nonetheless I will keep your comment in mind when I post an answer next time.